# How to hide questions in "Hot Network Topics"

Tags: support

Is there a way to hide questions in Hot Network Questions based on the community?

I know I can do it by tag so I am hoping there is a way to do it by community such as a generic tag that represents everything in that community.

For instance, I would like to hide anything from role playing games.

Comment: Are you talking about the HNQ sidebar or the full HNQ list on stackexchange.com?

Comment: The sidebar.  This chrome plugin did the job: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hide-hot-network-question/jommfgnflipjalbpbgcfghdpoeijpoab